# jquery $.get(...) one at a time

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, response

i have a page with many actions on it, which triggers with $.get, but i want to run one at a time, rather then all triggering at once, that is lots of load time.. so what is the solution for me on this?

well before you give answer.. i dont want to trigger based on time, i want to trigger after each request is completely done from ajax, then go and continue with loop for ajax after first one is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to execute **synchronous** requests? if so, you need to use jQuery's `ajax` method instead of `get`, setting `async:false`.

check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**EDIT**

As one commenter properly pointed, making sync requests hangs the only thread javascript code has. That means no animations or other code running while you wait for the requests to finish.

An interesting option would be to "chain" your requests, executing the next request in the previous one callback like this:

```
$.get('ajax/first-call.html', function(data) {

  $.get('ajax/second-call.html', function(data){
    //etc
  }
});
```

Comment: be careful with synchronous requests as the browser may hang whilst the request is in process.

Comment: what you think of queue as andew prefered

Answer (score 2):

You can setup your own custom queue in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

1. Populate your queue with all the functions you want to execute.
2. Each function is a single call to $.get().
3. In the callback for each $.get function, call the dequeue() function to start up the next ajax call.

Comment: Great answer although it should be mentioned that `dequeue` needs to be called after setting up the queue, outside of the $.get callback functions to initiate the first request. Also, the `queue` and `dequeue` functions need to be applied to a jQuery selector. I used `$('body').queue()`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an ajax queue.

I've used [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue) before, and it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will only request four HTTP calls at once for the same domain. The others will be queued up and executed in serial. So the browser already implements some queuing on these requests.